# XeLaTeX with fontspec gives “Undefined control sequence” error after MiKTeX update - volume 2

Tags: xetex, miktex, fontspec

I have the very same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295126. But in my case, repeatedly running the two MiKTeX updaters does not solve the problem. I also tried running both package managers, synchronizing the database, and running both updaters again. I can see in the log that my LaTeX3 packages are outdated but then why doesn't the updater update them?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

Log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.4.25)  25 APR 2016 13:39
entering extended mode
**"D:/Marci/Google Drive/tex/nodecolon.tex"
("D:/Marci/Google Drive/tex/nodecolon.tex"
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 70 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
) (C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty
Package: etex 2016/01/11 v2.6 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count87
)
Package: expl3 2013/10/13 v4597 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Basic definitions
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2013/08/17 v4584 L3 Argument expansion
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2013/09/16 v4592 L3 Token lists
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3seq.sty
Package: l3seq 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Sequences and stacks
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3int.sty
Package: l3int 2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3quark.sty
Package: l3quark 2013/07/21 v4564 L3 Quarks
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prg.sty
Package: l3prg 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3clist.sty
Package: l3clist 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3token.sty
Package: l3token 2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prop.sty
Package: l3prop 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Property lists
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3msg.sty
Package: l3msg 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3file.sty
Package: l3file 2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count94
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count98
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3skip.sty
Package: l3skip 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3keys.sty
Package: l3keys 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count99
\l_keys_choice_int=\count100
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3fp.sty
Package: l3fp 2013/07/09 v4521 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count109
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3box.sty
Package: l3box 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3coffins.sty
Package: l3coffins 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3color.sty
Package: l3color 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3luatex.sty
Package: l3luatex 2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count110
\g__cctab_stack_int=\count111
)
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3candidates.sty
Package: l3candidates 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
))
(C:\Users\Marci\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.s
ty
Package: xparse 2013/10/13 v4597 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count112
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count113
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count115
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count116
)
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \sys_if_engine_luatex:T
```

Comment: Remove the l3-packages packages with the package manager (user) and reinstall them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update

Comment: @egreg It was not solved by a software update. I specifically mention in the second sentence that running the software updater over and over did not help.

Comment: @marczellm Reinstalling the wrongly installed package is software update.

Comment: @egreg maybe mark it as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation or similar?